# Inject URL to Display On Footer On One Page Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, footer

I need to add a URL to the footer of a site but appending the URL to only one page. Since I use a global footer, I am wondering if there is a way I can use JavaScript to call that page class and force it to inject the URL to the footer, along with the other links.

Comment: A bit more information will be useful if you want to get a good answer - How do you link your global footer? What server-side language do you use? What platform?

Comment: Agreed.  While it's pretty trivial to do this in javascript, there might be a better way using a server-side language.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov I use Wordpress, the Global Footer is linked using WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/footer.php` and somewhere (like in the `<footer>` tag you may add the following code:

```
<?php
    if($post->ID == 666) /* Where 666 stays for the ID of the page you want to add the additional URL.*/
    {
         ?>
         Write whatever HTML you like.
         <?php
    }
?>
```

To find your page's ID quickly, you may first write at the same place:

```
<?php
    echo $post->ID;
?>
```

then go to your page and see what ID is written.

PROs and CONs:
(-) When you need to update or change the theme, you will need to repeat this step.
(+) No need to make 'dirty' javascript injection from a blog article.

Comment: Thank you for this implementation in PHP! I will be trying it out! I also appreciate the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted to update this to one page because no other URLs within the global footer needed to be updated. What I did was I injected the JavaScript on to the page by calling the page class and the div class containing the footer links.

```
$('.page-name .footer-class').append('<a href="https://www.example.com/">Injected URL</a>');
```